# Where's runuser?

Tags: sudo, upstart, services, su

I'm making an upstart job, and I need to run an executable as another user.  Nothing fancy like `su` provides, and none of the mixed-up SELinux contexts that come along with it.  A quick internet search recommends `runuser` over `su` for this task, but `runuser` is nowhere to be found on Ubuntu 13.10.

Should I be using `su` on Ubuntu--will it be smart enough to avoid full authorization?  Would a resulting job be portable to other distros, or will I run into SELinux issues?

Ultimately, what's the best way to change users in an upstart job?

**Update**

Apparently upstart >= 1.4 supports `setuid` and `setgid`, but they're limited in that they affect all of the job pre-*/post-* scripts, not just the primary script/exec.  It'd still be nice to have a way to properly drop to another user for a single command.  I've considered using `stop-start-daemon`, but it overlaps too much with upstart and will likely cause `expect` to behave oddly.

Comment: I think this link may help you http://serverfault.com/questions/518713/where-is-the-runuser-command-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: @AvinashRaj I saw that, but the user's question is never properly answered.  I know how to use `su` and `sudo`--I also know that they're not meant for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/911207) regarding this problem.

Suggested work around the the limitation is to create a separate jobs to handle the pre/post conditions whilst running as root. You would need to correctly setup start/stop conditions: Job emulating pre stanza (pre-job.conf) would have to start on conditions defined currently for your job (main-job.conf), your current job will have to run on pre-job started, job emulating post stanza (post-job.conf) will have to start on main-job stopped.

Comment: Not quite what I expected, but seems to do the trick, and it's not too hackish--probably better than runuser/su.